# Usage of "break off one's plans"

Tags: word-usage, expressions

I have heard the expression *break off one's plans* in the context of breaking off one's holidays due to an emergency.

> He had to **break off** his holidays to come back for the meeting.

What are other examples of its usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Break off" has two meanings that I can think of off the top of my head. The one that you refer to in your question can simply be replaced by "cancel" in all instances.

*He broke off our plans* <-> *He canceled our plans*

The second "break off" is a more literal phrase and it implies that something was removed from a greater whole.

"He broke off from the rest of the team." means he left the rest of the team and went off on his own. Likewise, "He accidentally broke off a piece of the vase." means part of the vase was removed from the vase.

Comment: I disagree. "Break off" (in that sense) means more than "cancel". It means "cancel something which is already in progress".

Comment: I kindly disagree Colin. "Break off" in that sense doesn't necessarily mean to cancel something already in progress. If I break off plans you and I have to meet at the bar for a drink, the event hasn't actually started yet—though your assessment is 100% accurate in regards to OP's original query.

Answer (score 2):

["Break"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/broke+off) here means:

> to dissolve or annul (often followed by off ): 
>   So, it's not necessarily followed by "off". It could just be "break."

Other examples include:

> He broke off their engagement
>   They had to break off the dinner party
>
> We broke off going to the zoo today.

Comment: Can you give an example of "break" being used in this sense without "off"? I can't think of many extended events that you can "break", apart from a journey; but "breaking a journey" implies you're going to resume, where "breaking off a journey" would imply you are not.

Answer (score 2):

[Break off](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/break_off) has two meanings:

> 1. To end abruptly, either temporarily or permanently.
>    2. To remove a piece from a whole by breaking or snapping.

Your example, *break off one's plans*, is the first meaning.

Browsing [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=11533527), we can find plenty of examples:

> What caused you to break off the last engagement?
> Break off communication with the Earth shuttle at once.
> ... prompting him to break off relations with his Venetian publisher in 1730.
> ... demanded that their leaders break off the negotiations.

[Break](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/break) (definitions 6, 7, 8 in OALD) can be used without *off* in a similar sense, meaning to "end something" by interruption, forceful action (as if snapping), or by severing a connection. For example, you can *break someone's fall*, *break a fast*, *break a tie* (to determine a winner) or *break all ties* (to stop talking to someone).